# Mongodb sub documents

Tags: mongodb, select, subdocument

Is there any way in the new releases of the mongodb to:

1. select a sub document
   or an object in an array inside a document and not to retrieve the parent document,
2. then run over and search again for an item/subdocument this time in the memory.

Let's say a User document has a list inside it of items that one of them has a price over 50$.
I just want this item and not to retrieve the User document, then search again for the certain item.

I read it could be possible in the next releases but couldn't find it .
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Examples are from the mongo shell.

> 1. select a sub document or an object in an array inside a document and not to retrieve the parent document

For a subdocument, use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

```
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "embedded" : { "foo" : "bar", "counts" : [1, 2, 3, 4] } })
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 0}, { "_id" : 0, "embedded" : 1})
{ "embedded" : { "foo" : "bar", "counts" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] } }
```

For an object in an array, you can also use projection but only for a slice starting at the beginning of the array

```
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 1, "prices" : [100, 22, 63, 234] })
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 1}, { "_id" : 0, "prices" : { "$slice" : 2 } })
{ "prices" : [ 100, 22 ] }
```

or the first array element matching a condition on the array elements using the positional operator `$`

```
> db.test.find({ "prices" : { "$lt" : 100 } }, { "_id" : 0, "prices.$" : 1 })
{ "prices" : [ 22 ] }
```

or the first element matching an `$elemMatch` condition:

```
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 2, "users" : [{ "name" : Jill, "age" : 32 }, { "name" : Joe, "age" : 55 }, { "name" : Sam, "age" : 96 }])
> db.test.find({"_id" : 2}, { "users" : { "$elemMatch" : { "age" : { "$gt" : 50 } } } })
{ "_id" : 2, "users" : [ { "name" : "Joe", "age" : 55 } ] }
```

> then run over and search again for an item/subdocument this time in the memory

What do you mean by this? I'm happy to try to answer if you clarify. MongoDB loads documents into memory as required. If the same set of documents are queried over and over, they will reside in memory and be served from memory as long as the whole set fits in memory (including indexes).

Comment: The idea is not to query again in the memory just to have the relevant data and save running time Thanks for the detailed answer i'll go over it and test !

Answer (score 0):

You can use $elemMatch. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

So, in your case it would be something like below:

> db.users.insert({"items": [ {"name":"A1", "price":10}, {"name":"B1", "price":20}]})
> db.users.insert({"items": [ {"name":"A2", "price":40}, {"name":"B2", "price":60}]})
>
> db.users.find({"items": {$elemMatch:{price:{$gt:30}}}}) 
> { "_id" : ObjectId("53e0c750e47ff836d16c66f4"), "items" : [ { "name" : "A2", "price" : 40 }, { "name" : "B2", "price" : 60 } ] }

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this bring me the entire collection and i will still need to run over it and find again the necessary embedded object